# Python finding the days difference between today's date and a date in a nested list

Tags: python, datetime, nested-lists

I have the following nested list:

`[['3574', 'A+', '2021-03-24'], ['3575', 'O+', '2021-04-03'], ['3576', 'AB-', '2021-04-09'], ['3580', 'AB+', '2021-04-27'], ['3589', 'A+', '2021-05-08'], ['3590', 'B-', '2021-05-11']]`

I am wanting to use the import date from datetime to help find the difference between todays date and the dates in the list then if the date is greater than 30 days difference print the date. I have tried the following but it is not working and I am not sure how to fix it.

```
today = date.today()
i = 0
for i in stock:
    stock_date = stock[i][2]
    some_date = date.fromisoformat(stock_date)
    days_diff = (today - some_date).days
    if days_diff < 30:
        print('all good')
    else:        
        print(stock[i][0])
    i += 1
```

Comment: Forget BASIC/Fortran loops. The Python `for` loop is essentially about stepping through a sequence. `for i in stock` is the right pattern, although the variable name is lousy, but you have to remember that `i` is going to be one of the actual elements of `stock`, not an index.

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite your counter `i` with the iterator variable `for i in stock:`. Use different names.

```py
today = date.today()
i = 0
for item in stock:
    stock_date = stock[i][2]
    some_date = date.fromisoformat(stock_date)
    days_diff = (today - some_date).days
    if days_diff < 30:
        print('all good')
    else:        
        print(stock[i][0])
    i += 1
```

Or simply:

```py
today = date.today()
for item in stock:
    stock_date = item[2]
    some_date = date.fromisoformat(stock_date)
    days_diff = (today - some_date).days
    if days_diff < 30:
        print('all good')
    else:        
        print(item[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

I is already your array elemnt and can't be used again as integer

```
from datetime import date
stock = [['3574', 'A+', '2021-03-24'], ['3575', 'O+', '2021-04-03'], ['3576', 'AB-', '2021-04-09'], ['3580', 'AB+', '2021-04-27'], ['3589', 'A+', '2021-05-08'], ['3590', 'B-', '2021-05-11']]

today = date.today()
i = 0
for i in stock:
    stock_date = i[2]
    some_date = date.fromisoformat(stock_date)
    days_diff = (today - some_date).days
    if days_diff < 30:
        print('all good')
    else:        
        print(i[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply if you want to use **i** as index you need to use integer and you are using **stock**. stock is nested list so you are using list element as index. Use function that will return number of list elements like this

```
for i in range(len(stock)):
stock_date = stock[i][2]
some_date = date.fromisoformat(stock_date)
days_diff = (today - some_date).days
if days_diff < 30:
    print('all good')
else:        
    print(stock[i][0])

i += 1
```